# How to show a custom taxonomy in the theme?

Tags: posts, categories, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom post type: `register_post_type()` and custom taxonomy: `register_taxonomy()`, but when trying to show the categories made to the post type in the theme **single-{post_type}**.php they do not appear.

I am using this but without success:

```
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);

foreach($categories as $category){
  echo $category->name;
}
```

Comment: Try using get_the_terms() instead of get_the_category(). The latter is for the default "category" taxonomy only, not custom taxonomies you register yourself. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

Comment: @Michelle You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @JacobPeattie done! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `get_the_terms()` instead of `get_the_category()`. The latter is for the default "category" taxonomy only, not custom taxonomies you register yourself. See developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms